# Is it correct to say "students salute the flag in the schoolyard before first class"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

In some countries, school children must salute in front of their school flag in the morning before beginning their first class.

**Do you have that custom in England or America?**

If yes, **what is the phrase for it?**

If no, **can we say "*students salute the flag in the schoolyard before first class*"**?

Comment: The "cultural" issue is off topic anyway, leaving just more off topic proofreading. You've been here long enough to know that.

Comment: We don't in Britain.

Comment: Many parents in the UK would be angry if their children were forced to salute a flag. I would have been.

Comment: In some countries they might well be asked to stand respectfully to attention while the flag was raised or the national anthem played.

Comment: OP is asking for an expression, not for value judgements.

Comment: @rajesun - our goal here is to educate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The US has (if anything) a much more extensive ritual, involving standing before the flag and saying the Pledge of Allegiance. (Strictly speaking it's optional, but in my experience almost everyone complies.)

Comment: (The pledge also includes the phrase "one nation under God," which has led to a number of Supreme Court cases. Only in America...)

Comment: @alphabet - There was a TV series, 'The Haunting of Bly Manor' supposedly set in England, but obviously filmed in a Hollywood back lot. A boy character aged 7 or so went to school and the teacher had little Union Jacks on his desk and a great big one on a pole at the front of the schoolroom, along with a framed picture of Queen Elizabeth. These would have destroyed the credibility of the show if it wasn't in tatters already (e.g. the weird accents. either like dukes and duchesses, or Dick Van Dyke-style chimneysweep).

Comment: @alphabet - also a 'British cop' who has a 1970s British cop cap, a 1920s button-up-to-the-neck jacket, and a NYPD 1930s style 'billy stick', and talked like a duke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, most public schools have a similar custom: they ask students to **recite the Pledge of Allegiance** at the start of the school day. This involves *standing* in front of the flag (while reciting the pledge), but not saluting it.

The custom you mention could indeed just be described as: "students salute the flag in the schoolyard before their first class." (Note: you need to put a "their" before "first class.")